# How to optimize a slow running for-loop on a large dataset?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, pyspark

I have a df of monthly data consisting of 4 columns: a, b, c, and d.

In my code below I run 3 steps:
(1) calculate all combinations of totals minus duplicates
(2) extend the df by 5 months
(3) for each column in step 2, extend each series from 1 to 5 months, with the extended series containing a suffix for the # months the original series has been shifted.

Here's the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)         
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)     

  df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['01-31-2023','02-28-2023','03-31-2023','04-30-2023', '05-31-2023']), 
'a': [3,4,5,6,3], 'b': [5,7,1,0,5], 'c':[3,4,2,1,3], 'd':[2,0,1,5,9]}).set_index('date')

#1. Generate all combinations of column totals

orig_cols = df.columns
for r in range(2, df.shape[1] + 1):
    for cols in it.combinations(orig_cols, r):
        df["_".join(cols)] = df.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)
        
#2. Extend df 5 more months

first_date = df.first_valid_index()
end_forecast_horizon = '2023-10-30'
min_lead = 1 
max_lead = 5

expand_dates = pd.date_range(first_date, end_forecast_horizon, freq='M')
df = df.reindex(expand_dates)

#3. For each series from step 2, create new columns with leads from 1 to 5 months out

for col in df.columns:
  for i in range(min_lead,max_lead):
    df["%s_%s"%(col,i)] = df[col].shift(i)

df
```

And here is the df (partial results shown):

[image]

When I apply this code to a much larger df (starting with 20,000 columns rather than 4 as with this example) the code is taking an extremely long time to run (using Azure Databricks).  The issues appears to be step #3 since steps #1 and #2 run pretty fast.  Is there a way I can optimize step #3?  Or the entire code?  Is this exercise best suited for Pyspark?

Over time I plan to add more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the loop for each column:

```
#3. ...
dfs = [df.shift(i).add_suffix(f'_{i}') for i in range(min_lead, max_lead)]
df = pd.concat([df, *dfs], axis=1)
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks...Just curious, for step #1 shown above can it be written to run faster on a large dataset?

Comment: I don't think so, really. I would also have used this method with `combinations`. Maybe the same method as above with a comprehension then pd.concat.